# Windows 7 x64 with RAM volume 4GB hangs on when file upload in Java servlet is started

Tags: windows-7, memory, bios, java

It is actually not the coding but mostly configuration question. I have :

- Windows 7 x64
- ASUS P5KC motherboard
- Intel Core Quad Q6600
- GeForce 6800 GT
- RAM 4GB (then 8 GB - when i added 4 GB more even memory remapping does not help)

Previously i had 2 slots of RAM memory by 1GB and all worked fine but then i replaced them with only one slot of memory of volume 4GB and now each time i started file upload using Java servlet on any web page my computer hangs without any error / rebooting / record in Event log... For example this site causes hanging - files.mail.ru when i try to upload something.

**Temporarily i fixed this by disabling "Memory Remap" option in BIOS but this causes limitation of RAM memory to 3GB.**

Java forums do not answer my question so i do not know what can be the reason of such behavior, maybe someone knows the answer which update / fix should be installed / done to fix mentioned issue?

**Update 1:**
 Not only Java can cause hanging but FlyLinkDC++ client for local networks too. All memory test ran fine, without any error (Memtest86+, GoldMemory, PCDoctor and other run fine)...

**Update 2:**
 Java servlet on any site forces my PC to hang, site like files.mail.ru was taken just as an example ...

Comment: Your computer hangs when you upload a file from your computer to some Java servlet in Russia? Do you really think that servlets have anything to do with this problem? If it's a hardware or windows configuration problem, Java has nothing to do with it, and you won't find any answer on Java forums.

Comment: Turn memory remapping back on and boot with a [memtest86+](http://memtest.org) CD. Let it run for a few hours. If you have any errors, it's a hardware or BIOS setttings issue. If you don't, it's most likely a software issue. Let's start by splitting the problem space in half.